# php wordpress $_POST incremental shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Maybe the title is a bit tricky but I'm not able to explain well my issue in few words.
I'm using contact form 7. So basically on the frontend I have this code:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap classmateria materia__1">
<input type="text" name="materia__1" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false">
</span>
```

I'm building a function which generates a xml file from some fields in the frontend, and the function is this:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'CF7_pre_send' );
function CF7_pre_send($cf7) {
$output .= $_POST['materia__1'];
file_put_contents("wp-content/uploads/cf7outputtest.xml", $output);
}
```

Basically with the command `$_POST['materia__1'];` i'm able to print the output of the above selection for the class "materia__1".
Is there a way to achieve that same result by doing something like `$_POST['materia__[i]']; for i=0; i++;` ? Or another way to do that? With my form I can generate how many  I want, so I can't create $_POST['materia__2'], $_POST['materia__3'] etc...
I'm not a php expert so please help me with that code :)

Thanks a lot,

Luca

Comment: What shortcode are you talking about? One _contained in_ the text data of one of those $_POST entries? Then you need to apply the appropriate function to parse and transform those, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question. Now is clearer!

Comment: So you are not talking about what is called a “shortcode” in the WordPress universe at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays instead of indexed names.

In HTML `name="materia[]"`

In PHP `print_r($_POST[materia]);`

Values will be in

```
$_POST['materia'][0], $_POST['materia'][1], etc.
```

Using foreach loop

```
foreach ($_POST['materia'] as $item) {
    echo $k . ' - ' . $item; // 0 - value, 1 - value, etc.
}
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't do that as I'm using a third party plugin which generates these fields. So I guess that it's not possible with indexed names?

Comment: Well it wasn't so difficult... but I've started to code in php since yesterday so I'm quite a newbie.
I'll use a for $i = 1,   $output .= $_POST['titolo__' . $i];   i++

and it seems to work :)

Comment: @LucaDeFassi: it maybe 'works' but its absolutely bad approach. Only one correct solution is using arrays and `[]` in names. Its your website and your future problems ;-)